# How to show image caption in a slideshow with backstretch?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-backstretch

I'm using jQuery backstretch slideshow:

```
  $.backstretch([
      "http://dl.dropbox.com/u/515046/www/outside.jpg"
    , "http://dl.dropbox.com/u/515046/www/garfield-interior.jpg"
    , "http://dl.dropbox.com/u/515046/www/cheers.jpg"
  ], {duration: 3000, fade: 750});
```

I want to show the title of each image when the image is shown.
For the image `outside.jpg` I wanna show `outside` and for `cheers.jpg` I wanna show `cheers`. (not the file name, but content in a span or some element). How is it possible to show the image title when the current image is shown?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/b5S5V.jpg

Something like this image is acceptable (just need to get the string related to the image when the image is shown on the slideshow, the next image string when the next image is shown on the slideshow.)

Note: No styling is required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved!
this project on GitHub!
https://github.com/biwin/backstretch-slideshow-captions